# How to make it look like falling snow?

Tags: c++, bgi

I have tried to make it look like falling snow but snow is coming from everywhere and I have to make falling snow from library graphics.h. I don't know how to make it move but I already add x and y. For `int speed` I don't know to use it I see from other code which is from movement of the ball. This code is for my assignment, can you guys help me?

```
#include <graphics.h>

class Snow
{
    private:
        int x,y;
        int color;
        int speed;

    public:
        Snow(int _x, int _y, int _color, int _speed)
        {
            x=_x;
            y=_y;
            color=_color;
            speed=_speed;
        }
        int getColor()
        {
            return color;
        }
        int getSpeed()
        {
            return speed;
        }
        int getX()
        {
            return x;
        }
        int getY()
        {
            return y;
        }
        void setX(int value)
        {
            //x=rand();
            x=value;
        }
        void setY (int value)
        {
            //y=rand();
            y=value;
        }
        void setColor(int value)
        {
            color=value;
        }
        void setSpeed(int value)
        {
            speed=value;
        }

        void draw()
        {
            setcolor(color);
            setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,color);
            fillellipse(x,y,2,2);
        }
        void undraw()
        {
            setcolor(BLACK);
            fillellipse(x,y,2,2);
        }
        void move()
        {
            undraw();
            x=rand() % getmaxwidth();
            y=rand() % getmaxheight();
            draw();


        }
};

int main()
{
    int screenWidth = getmaxwidth();
    int screenHeight = getmaxheight();
    initwindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Snowy day");

    Snow p1(0,0,WHITE,10);

    while (!kbhit())
    {
        delay(100);
        p1.move();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is graphics.h?

Comment: graphics.h is library in c++. You can google it if still don't know

Comment: `graphics.h` is not part of the Standard Library. Is this a console app? I'm guessing so, but things like this need to be clear or we can't help.

Comment: To clarify, Stack Overflow isn't just a basic Q&A; it's a knowledge repository. If J. Random User comes along two years from now and reads your question, they won't know the context, as they have to go figure out what `graphics.h` is from. Aim for questions that are both clear and self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

You should use speed in move function. For example:

```cpp
void move() {
    undraw();
    x=rand() % getmaxwidth();
    // fall
    y += speed;
    draw();
}
```